# the number with the greatest priority

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Given an integer of number and their priority, return the number with the greatest priority
Say

```
int[] number={0,1,3,4}
int[] priority={1,3,4,2} //All numbers are distinct
```

I would want to have the value 3(with priority 4 which is the largest), how could I achieve that easily and efficiently?

Comment: I could not understand the question at all. Can you explain about your priority array nmaps to the number array ?

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in priority queues: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: Obviously the two arrays are matched by indices.

Comment: We should not down vote a question because the answer is easy. Maybe the person is new to programming.

Comment: @kasavbere, thanks for your understanding, I am not new to programming, it just that I wish to know what is the simple and efficient way to do this in C# :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly without any suggestion about using other objects, try using `MAX()` and `IndexOf()` since you have mentioned that all numbers in `priority` are distinct,

```
int _value = number[Array.IndexOf(priority, priority.Max())];
```

Comment: This answer does not satisfy its own criteria, since it using another object by calling ToList, which instantiates, populates, and returns a new List<int> with the contents of the array.  There's a static Array.IndexOf method that allows this approach without having to create the list.

Comment: The answer provided by @KonsolLabapen is the most efficient and most elegant one. So how was this answer selected instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<int,int> priority;
```

This would be a better starting point than 2 arrays. The key is a number and the value its priority. This map can then be used to check priority of any number.

Although in your case all you would need to do is to find index of element with max value in 2nd array, and output element at that index in first array

Comment: Yes, if you use a dictionary you can then just sort them by their key value. Everything is in one place. Don't use two arrays it'll be a pain to track. If you absolutly must (e.g. we're doing your homework) you would need to get the index of your priority, then use that to get the index of the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
int max=0;
for(int i=1; i<priority.length; i++)
   if(priority[max] < priority[i])
          max = i;

return num[max];
```

no object to create, O(n) complexity -- the best you can do since you have to visit each. Also no object means no memory expense since you are only using the primitive `int max`

- memory complexity O(1)
- time complexity O(n)

Answer (score 0):

I think following is what you are looking for:

```
IDictionary<int, int> priority = new Dictionary<int, int>(); // priority, value
priority.Add(1, 3);
priority.Add(2, 4);
priority.Add(3, 5);

Console.WriteLine(priority[2]); //get value with priority 2
```

Comment: This approach works only if no two values can have the same priority.  If 32 and 45 both have priority 4, you'll get a duplicate key error when you try to add the second to the list.

Comment: It is mentioned in the question that
int[] priority={1,3,4,2} //All numbers are distinct
I considered it while posting the answer. :)

Comment: The fact that the example data has distinct priorities does not necessarily mean the real data will.

Answer (score 0):

```
var highestPriorityNumber = number.Select((n, i) => new {p = priority[i], n})
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.p)
    .First().n;
```